# How do I add a folder to a specific category in a document library?

Tags: document-library

This has got to be an easy one, but I can't figure it out. I have an existing document library that has several categories with documents within each. In one of those categories I would like to add a new folder. I see the Create Folder button in the library tools, but when I create the folder, it creates it in its own unnamed category. How do I create a new folder in an existing category in a document library?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating document set as it comes with property and then you can associate category.